# Configuring Notepad++ to run knitr2pdf

Tags: command-line, notepad++, pdflatex

Sorry for such a basic question but since I do not have a degree in programming...

I am a user of R, knitr and Notepad++.
I was trying to configure Notepad++ to run pdflatex and knitr(`knit2pdf`). By googling I found how to do it for pdflatex but I did not find anything for sweave/knitr. The following are the good ones for pdflatex

http://www2.sofi.su.se/~mbe/docs/npp_r_latex.pdf

http://www.tlhiv.org/ma497/software/

I inserted `cmd /c cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && pdflatex.exe -shell-escape "$(FILE_NAME)"` into the run>run menu in Notepad++. I do not fully understand the command though. I will appreciate any help on this.

1. Please direct me if you can to any resource for learning these commands.
2. I will be grateful to get any help in configuring Notepad++ for running knitr.

Comment: when you're on superuser (and here too), note that when you rollover a tag that you have added (knitr), it will show you the number of followers. Many power users set up a list of tags that they watch the questions for. You only have ~350 followers looking at your question. Many topics have 1,000s of followers. Look for other tags to related topics that can get you more readers. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @ Shellter for the advice. I will remember this for in future. It would be good if the question goes to superuser...

Comment: This is actually on topic here.  But since OP asked for migration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the NPPExec plugin ([Link to NppExec](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/forums/forum/672146)) in Notepad++. I used the following command to:

- Take the current sweave(say test.rnw) file and run knitr2pdf on it. It would generate test.tex (One need's to change path to Rscript.exe accordingly)

  ```
  cmd /c cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" &&  "C:/.../bin/Rscript.exe" -e "knitr::knit2pdf('"$(NAME_PART).rnw"')
  ```
- Run pdflatex to test.tex. It would generate test.pdf

  ```
  pdflatex.exe -shell-escape "$$(NAME_PART).tex"
  ```
- Open test.pdf in a pdfview that updates the PDF file when the new one is generated

  ```
  npp_run "C:\Users\...\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).pdf"
  ```

We need to hit F6 and a window opens up. We can put the following command chunk there and save it. Rest is self explanatory.

```
cmd /c cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" &&  "C:/.../bin/Rscript.exe" -e "knitr::knit2pdf('"$(NAME_PART).rnw"') pdflatex.exe -shell-escape "$$(NAME_PART).tex" npp_run "C:\Users\...\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).pdf"
```

*References:* NppExec plugin manual and NppExec plugin Help

Comment: Please check if the formatting is okay now. Breaking up command lines is problematic since you can't copy them anymore.